# Real numbers having the form $\sqrt[p]{2021+\sqrt[q]{a}}$ that can be written as linear combinations of some roots of unity.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity

I encountered a hard problem as below.

Find all the real numbers having the form $\sqrt[p]{2021+\sqrt[q]{a}}$ that can be written as linear combinations (with rational coefficients) of some roots of unity, where $p,q$ are prime numbers (can be the same) and $a$ is a positive integer with $a>1$ that is not the $q$ th power of an integer.

I tried something below.

Let $r=\sqrt[p]{2021+\sqrt[q]{a}}$, then $r$ can be written as a polynomial of a root of unity $\zeta$ where $\zeta^n=1$. Let $r=g(\zeta)$. Let $h(x)=(g^p(x)-2021)^q-a$, then $h(\zeta)=0$. I quit here. Simply by looking at the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(r)/\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$ will not solve the problem. The biggest problem is we don't know the degree of $g(x)$.

I don't have the correct answer of this problem. How to solve it?

Comment: $a^{1/q} = r^p-2021$ lies in a cyclotomic (thus Galois) extension. Does that imply $q=2$? Since adding other irrational $q$-th roots of integers like $2^{1/3}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ are not Galois. Not sure if this argument also works for taking the $p$th root on the outer layer. In that case, $2021+\sqrt{a}$ is a perfect $p$-th power in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})$.
PS. I was in the same competition. I failed this problem at scene too, Just some retrospective thoughts.

Comment: Well, Kronecker and Weber tell us that every abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q} $ is contained in some cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q} (\zeta) $ and vice versa. So we need the Galois group of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[p] {2021+\sqrt[q]{a}}$ to be abelian.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for your advise. Kronecker–Weber theorem is indeed helpful!

Comment: Because the constant 2021 appears, I need to ask whether this might be from some math contest? I don't suspect you about anything unethical, but we have a strict policy stating that questions from currently running (online or postal) contests are not allowed. If this is from a contest, may be you can post a link to their website? Of course, contest organizers don't have a monopoly on using the current year in place of a variable, but it is a popular thing to do :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This question is from a contest which was already over and of course, I raised this question after the contest. This is the link: https://damo.alibaba.com/alibaba-global-mathematics-competition/?lang=en . The organiser never announces the answer and that's why I want to know the solution.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated :-)

Comment: By basic Galois theory (= the trivial direction of Kronecker-Weber) $K=\Bbb{Q}(r)$ is an abelian Galois extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. Hence so is $F=\Bbb{Q}(\root q\of a)$. This means that either $q=2$ or $\root q\of a$ is an integer. In the latter case we can deduce that also $p=2$. In the former case there is the more interesting possibility that
$\root p\of {2021+\sqrt{a}}$, $a$ a non-square, denests. This cannot happen unless the norm $(2021+\sqrt{a})(2021-\sqrt a)=2021^2-a^2$ is a $p$th power.

Comment: Because $2021=43\cdot47$ with $43\equiv47\equiv-1\pmod4$, it is impossible to write $2021^2$ as a sum of two squares non-trivially, forcing $p>2$. I haven't found any non-trivial solutions yet, but it looks like an interesting problem.

Comment: Hmm. $2021-a^2$ could be negative, leaving the case $p=2$ still open?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your brilliant advice. Actually the latter case could be eliminated since the requirement tells us that $\sqrt[q]{a}$ is never an integer.